# Directly add [ ] to an object means what?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book named Eloquent Javascript.

In Chapter 6 I found a syntax I can not understand, `[ ]` can be directly added to an object.

What does this usage mean?

```
function UnderlinedCell(inner) {
    this.inner = inner;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth = function() {
    return this.inner.minWidth();
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minHeight = function() {
    return this.inner.minHeight() + 1;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
    return this.inner.draw(width, height - 1)
    .concat([repeat("-", width)]);
};

function dataTable(data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var headers = keys.map(function(name) {
    return new UnderlinedCell(new TextCell(name));
    });
    var body = data.map(function(row) {
        return keys.map(function(name) {
            return new TextCell(String(row[name]));
        });
    });
    return [headers].concat(body);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. I don't see [] (empty array) being added to an object anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `[]` around a variable just means to create an array whose element is that variable.  This can then be used

```
return [headers].concat(body);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = headers;
var new_array = array.concat(body);
return new_array;
```

What the function is doing is returning an array whose first element is the header row, and the remaining elements are each data row from `body`.

Answer (score 0):

With the line `return [headers].concat(body);` you say that the variable "headers" is an array. This way you can call the concat() function on it.
You usually don't need the brackets, but in this case, you want to concatenate the arrays "headers" and "body" into a new array "headers".

Hope I could answer your question.

Comment: `headers = [].concat(body)` replaces the value of `header` with `body`, it doesn't concatenate the two arrays.